# ansible passing multiple commands with expect module

Tags: ansible

Hi all how can i pass multiple commands with expect module.

```
 - name: setup tech
     expect: 
       command: 
         - date; 
         - time /run/app.run
       responses: 
         'update': 'yes'
```

The error was: pexpect.exceptions.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a command through the shell you should pass  /bin/bash -c "command
"

```
 - name: setup tech
     expect: 
       command: /bin/bash -c "date; time /run/app.run"
       responses: 
         'update': 'yes'
```